# remove rows of data based on one of any criteria

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm trying to create some association rules with the aprori algorithm between different error messages. 
There are several errors that I do not want to consider, So I want to remove rows that contain these select errors. 
My problem is I can only remove one error using the code below.

```
mydata <-data[!(data$Message=="errormessageone") ,]
```

Is there an "or" operator that can be integrated into this in order to remove lines containing any of the 12 or so errors that I want to exclude from my data.

Something like the following.

```
mydata <-data[!(data$errorMessage=="errormessageone or errormessagetwo or errormessagethree") ,]
```

I know this is a basic question but this has really got me stumped.

Comment: suppose you have a vector of error messages called `errors`: `data[! data$errorMessage %in% errors,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
mydata <-data[!data$errorMessage %in% c("errormessageone","errormessagetwo", "errormessagethree"),]
```

Answer (score -1):

It typically looks like this (| is used for or):

```
mydata <-data[!(data$errorMessage=="errormessageone") | !(data$errorMessage=="errormessagetwo") | !(data$errorMessage=="errormessagethree"),]
```

In your case you do not want all of these error messages, so you should use and (&):

```
mydata <-data[!(data$errorMessage=="errormessageone") & !(data$errorMessage=="errormessagetwo") & !(data$errorMessage=="errormessagethree"),]
```